# npm does not support Node v10.16.0 but my version of npm does

Tags: node.js, npm

Getting a warning that

`npm does not support Node.js v10.16.0`.

However my version of npm is 6.9.0 which [is the version that is tied to 10.16.0](https://nodejs.org/ja/blog/release/v10.16.0/).

I've tried all the suggestions here on such as `sudo npm uninstall -g npm` but still getting the same error as the version that is reinstalled is 6.9.0

A full remove and install just gets me back to the original issue. Please stop suggesting `brew uninstall node`

Even a complete uninstall outlined below did not do the trick for longer than a day. I guess I'll just have to live with the issue. There does not seem to be a fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update NodeJS and NPM to the next versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237295/how-can-i-update-nodejs-and-npm-to-the-next-versions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v9.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0)

Comment: As I stated above the duplicates listed do not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is to uninstall both node and npm fully, and then reinstall the node which will bring the matching npm version. Using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) can simply node and npm version management a lot.

Manually uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Then go to /etc/apt/sources.list.d and remove any node list if you have. Then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947181/4185234) answer describes it all.

Comment: As stated above this does not solve the issue. A complete remove just puts it back in the original state. With node version 10.16.0 not compatible with npm 6.9.0

Comment: Completely remove and use NVM

Comment: Tried that. No luck. Even removed NVM. Then reinstall from https://nodejs.org/en/ Still same issue

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Mac Os 10.14.2.

Comment: Came in the next and found that I'm still getting this warning. I guess I'll just have to live with it