# npm 5.8.0 does not support Node.js v10.15.2 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-19.04

I am trying to build an application using `Node.js` integrated into `Visual Studio Code`. The most important versions of the software I have are:

The version of `Node.js` I have is `v10.15.2`.

The version I have for `npm` is `5.8.0`.

I have `Ubuntu 19.04` as OS.

It seems that there is a compatibility issue with the old `npm`.

So I tried to do the following operations to correctly install the last version of `npm`:

1) `npm uninstall -g npm`

2) `sudo npm cache clean -f`

3) `sudo npm install -g npm`

4) `npm -v` but it still gives `5.8.0`.

I followed the procedure described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562417/how-do-you-update-npm-to-the-latest-version) but it doesn't seem to be working.

In addition I found this useful [additional post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0) but nothing happened.

If useful I am also posting the output of the debugger in the print-screen below:

[image: error]

Lastly after those steps I receive the following confirmation:

[image: confirmation]

But as soon as I try to check the version `npm -v` it still gives `5.8.0`

**EDITS**

The following is the output after a couple of additional trials:

[image: latest_commands]

Thank you for pointing in the right direction to solve this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default version of `npm` for Node 10.15.2 is 6.4.1. Depending on how you installed, the ordering of directories in your `PATH` environment variable will make a difference. To view all `npm`s on your `PATH`, run:

```
which -a npm
```

Another helpful command is to list out your globally installed packages including where they're installed:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0
```

Comment: thank you for reading the question. I tried your suggestion and what I obtained is [this](https://i.imgur.com/ZaH7OQk.png). Any thoughts?

Comment: Interesting. You may need to check where Node is installed with `which -a node` and fix your `PATH` based on that. You could also run `ls -la /usr/local/bin/npm` to see if it's a symlink to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` since the listing shows 6.12.1 is installed there.

Comment: I edited the question with a couple of updates. There seems to be a symlink, that explains why is there the last correct version. what is the convention to include the `PATH` for that version?

Comment: Searching the `PATH` goes from left to right, with the leftmost being highest priority. For example `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` would look in `~/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`. If the symlink is incorrect then you'd need to change it or remove it and redo the npm install. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you that helps! your explanation combined with the answer you gave me couple of days ago solved the problem :)