# npm does not support Node.js v8.17.0

Tags: node.js

So the problem I am facing is that some packages in my `package.json` file required `node` version greater than `10`. So I have `nvm` package installed to manage `node` versions and when I do `node -v` it gives me this: `v12.19.0`. So if the node version is `12.19.0` then the error shouldn't come but I think this is a global version of node so when I do `npm` update, this comes up:

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v8.17.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'gulp-imagemin@7.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'imagemin-gifsicle@7.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'imagemin-jpegtran@7.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'imagemin-optipng@8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'imagemin-pngquant@9.0.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'imagemin-svgo@8.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'yargs@16.2.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'gifsicle@5.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'execa@4.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'jpegtran-bin@5.0.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'optipng-bin@7.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'execa@4.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'ow@0.17.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'pngquant-bin@6.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'execa@4.1.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'y18n@5.0.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'yargs-parser@20.2.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine { package: 'wrap-ansi@7.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=10' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v8.17.0', npm: '7.5.4' } }
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)

added 165 packages, removed 190 packages, changed 69 packages, and audited 1485 packages in 2m

54 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 vulnerabilities (4 low, 1 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

For some reasom the version the app is using is 8.17.0. I want to update it to greate than 10. How can I do that?

I am on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

*EDIT*

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "stash",
    "description": "Wordpress stack",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git@gitlab.com:undefinedio/stash.git"
    },
    "author": "Vincent Peters",
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babelify": "^7.3.0",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browserify": "^14.4.0",
        "buffer": "^5.0.6",
        "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^3.7.0",
        "gulp-composer": "^0.4.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-consolidate": "^0.2.0",
        "gulp-debug": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-filter": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-header": "^1.8.9",
        "gulp-iconfont": "^10.0.3",
        "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
        "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
        "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-streamify": "^1.0.2",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
        "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
        "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
        "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
        "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
        "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.1",
        "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
        "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1",
        "merge-stream": "^1.0.1",
        "node-bourbon": "^4.2.8",
        "node-neat": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
        "susy": "^2",
        "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
        "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
        "yargs": "^16.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "flickity": "^2.2.2",
        "flickity-imagesloaded": "^2.0.0",
        "gsap": "^1.20.2",
        "lazysizes": "^5.3.0",
        "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
        "viewport-units-buggyfill": "^0.6.2"
    }
}    },
    "dependencies": {
        "flickity": "^2.2.2",
        "flickity-imagesloaded": "^2.0.0",
        "gsap": "^1.20.2",
        "lazysizes": "^5.3.0",
        "scrollmagic": "^2.0.5",
        "viewport-units-buggyfill": "^0.6.2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that the currently installed npm is not compatible with the new node.

A solution has been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227017/401712):

> The solution is to uninstall npm and then reinstall node which will contain the correct version of npm.
>
> Here's how:
>
> 1. Uninstall npm.
>
>    Mac:
>    sudo npm uninstall -g npm
>
>    Windows:
>    npm uninstall -g npm
> 2. Install node from https://nodejs.org

Comment: But how do I tell how node.js was installed on the system so I can avoid issues with installing the above way? For instance, if it was installed with `apt` or some other method, it seems like there may be risks involved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the problem is in your `package.json` simply run `npm install` and it should work.

Comment: can you add your package.json file?

Comment: try maybe npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: added package,json