# npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

```
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v15.8.0 
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. 
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12. 
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-02-22T19_03_54_554Z-debug.log
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0

Comment: What version of npm are you using?  `npm --version`

Comment: @zero298 I am using 15.8.0

Comment: No, that's your `node --version`.  The latest [`npm --version`](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/be9f1525587d70c909da88b996220b374583d42a/package.json#L2) should not exceed `7.5.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js 15.x ships with `npm` 7.x, so this should not be happening if you are using the version of `npm` installed with the version of `node` you are running. The mismatch you see typically happens when someone has multiple versions installed through different mechanisms.

So, for example, if the version of `node` you're using is installed through `nvm` but somehow (typically through `PATH` manipulation or setting an alias) the version of `npm` you are using is from an old package installation, you may see an error like this.

In your case, the version of `npm` is very old (judging from the fact that it only supports up to Node.js v12.x). While you can upgrade it, that's probably just delaying the problem rather than solving it. Other weird things are likely to happen. You might be better served by running `command -v node` and `command -v npm` and figuring out why the `npm` path provided by that command is so different from the `node` path, and then fix that. (If they're not very different, then just update `npm` with `npm install -g npm`.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and good solution is to upgrade your npm version or the second option is to downgrade your node version.

Download older node version of Node from here

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/