# Error on calling 'npm run serve' on Vue CLI project

Tags: vue.js, npm

After creating a project with `vue create project`, and using cd to move there, trying to use `npm run serve` causes the following errors (first with sudo, then not):

#### w/ sudo

```
user@user:~/Desktop/Github/project$ sudo npm run serve
[sudo] password for user: 
npm does not support Node.js v10.19.0
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:32
  #unloaded = false
  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:22:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

#### without sudo

```
user@user:~/Desktop/Github/project$ npm run serve

> project@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 INFO  Starting development server...
10% building 2/5 modules 3 active ...abbage/Desktop/Github/project/src/main.tsError: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at module.exports (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
node:internal/crypto/hash:67
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:135:10)
    at module.exports (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.4.0
user@user:~/Desktop/Github/project$ node:internal/process/promises:265
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

RpcIpcMessagePortClosedError: Cannot send the message - the message port has been closed for the process 3166.
    at /home/user/Desktop/Github/project/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-v5/lib/rpc/rpc-ipc/RpcIpcMessagePort.js:47:47
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: undefined,
  signal: undefined
}

Node.js v17.4.0
user@user:~/Desktop/Github/project$
```

Calling `node -v` on the terminal returns: v17.4.0
and `npm -v` = 8.3.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227017/9630323 try this

Comment: You don't need `sudo`. And the other error is a known issue with running Node 17. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported