# I can't use NPM and Node.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v16.16.0
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dasgr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-13T07_50_38_342Z-debug.log
```

Comment: you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0

Answer (score -2):

ahh they just changed how you use a parameter. Previously you used --global or --g to install something globally or vise versa. Now you need to use --location=global/ --location=local if you want to install something locally that's all...

[for more clarity check this page!](https://exerror.com/npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-locationglobal-instead/)

Comment: Better link to the official documentation and possibly quote that. Maybe that's the reason for voting down, but please, SO users, if you downvote answers, it helps to add a reason so that people can improve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).